# Yii2 Codeception basic test gives an error on backend unit

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, codeception

I configure codeception following this, the official I guess, [tutorial](https://codeception.com/for/yii)

After running `codecept run` the frontend test are executed without errors but what I get from the backend is those line [backend](https://pastebin.com/pPHZki0H).
I definitely have a user table and the tests are run on completely default `Yii2-advanced` template. Also, I've set the `YII_ENV` to `test` in both front and backend. The login form that the test aims are the one in the `common` folder in the root directory :

```
<?php
namespace common\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;

/**
 * Login form
 */
class LoginForm extends Model
{
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $rememberMe = true;

    private $_user;


    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // username and password are both required
            [['username', 'password'], 'required'],
            // rememberMe must be a boolean value
            ['rememberMe', 'boolean'],
            // password is validated by validatePassword()
            ['password', 'validatePassword'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Validates the password.
     * This method serves as the inline validation for password.
     *
     * @param string $attribute the attribute currently being validated
     * @param array $params the additional name-value pairs given in the rule
     */
    public function validatePassword($attribute, $params)
    {
        if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
            $user = $this->getUser();
            if (!$user || !$user->validatePassword($this->password)) {
                $this->addError($attribute, 'Incorrect username or password.');
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Logs in a user using the provided username and password.
     *
     * @return bool whether the user is logged in successfully
     */
    public function login()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600 * 24 * 30 : 0);
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by [[username]]
     *
     * @return User|null
     */
    protected function getUser()
    {
        if ($this->_user === null) {
            $this->_user = User::findByUsername($this->username);
        }

        return $this->_user;
    }
}
```

What can cause this issue? Thank you in advance!
**EDIT** As I saw in the tutorial there is no test in `Backend\tests.unit Tests (0)` but my code tries to execute something.